# Rafter damage, is this white ants?

Tags: roof, damage, pest

I was inspecting my roof today as I believe that I have some possums in the roof.

I Looked at one rafter and saw some damage. Is this white [image]ants?
Only one rafter has this damage, no others around at all, I can't see any ants around but it is crumbly and can see some holes.

See pictures.
Any ideas, what should I be doing first, inspect it with pest company first?
Is it easy to replace such one rafter. Seems to me that you would have to take parts of the roof off?

[image]

Comment: looks like dry rot

Comment: Homes have been built using "used" lumber.  Is it possible that's the case here?

Comment: It does not look like termites ( guess that is what you mean by white ants).

Answer (score 2):

The holes just above the missing part and the way the missing part is textured, looks like powder post beetles.

Look for the same entry holes on other rafters. It seems on that one piece the entry holes are only on a certain color of wood, perhaps sapwood, not the heartwood.

You may be able to sister another new piece beside the damaged one, but do not do that until a pest exterminator gets a look at it. If the infestation is active, needless to say needs to be dealt with first.

In respect of repairs, the blue strap/tape that is over the rafter, and the insulation?? appears to have a gap or at least the material are not meeting the rafter the way I would expect it. Can you easily shove something between the rafter and anything above the rafter? It seems to me that if the rafter was supporting the roof sheathing there would be no space to run a strap over the rafter, and/or the insulation would be compressed more over the rafters(s). Just an observation from a picture with a limited view.

Comment: Thanks, I have researched it a bit more and it does look like powder post beetles, the type of damage and how the wood has been damaged. I appreciate your answer. Have got a pest inspection going to check on it

Comment: Could you investigate how much room is over the rafter since the blue tape has made it over it. I do not see how that could have been possible if the roof sheathing is supposed to be on top of the rafters...